# Why an inherited field does not belong to the final type

Tags: c#, inheritance, ninject

I have the following code

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    AnObject AProperty {get; set;}
}
public class ChildA : Parent { }
public class ChildB : Parent { }
```

When I access an instance of `ChildA` through reflection, I see that its member AProperty has `DeclaringType` equal to `Parent`. Sadly I'd like to rely on reflection to determine who is ChildA and who is ChildB.

**More context** : I am actually trying to bind `AProperty` via NInject with a when clause so that it resolves differently depending on the actual type of the object to be created. Here's an oversimplified example:

```
Kernel.Bind<AnObject>().ToConstructor(..).WhenAnyAncestorMatches(c =>
      c.Request.Target.Member
       .DeclaringType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ChildA))
Kernel.Bind<AnObject>().ToConstructor(..).WhenAnyAncestorMatches(c =>
      c.Request.Target.Member
       .DeclaringType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ChildB))
```

**Questions** :

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Will I have to set `AProperty` to `abstract` and override it on every `ChildX` ?
- Can I get the actual type in my `WhenAnyAncestorMatches` predicate?

Comment: I may be missing something obvious but how are you going to make any kind of decisión about `ChildA` or `ChilB` based on `AProperty` through reflection? It will always be asignable to both as its declared in the base type. Making the property `abstract` won't help either, any `AnObject` will be asignable to both and C# does not allow type variance in overriden members.

Comment: @InBetween: No, I am trying to make (to have NInject make) assertions on whether the injection context (`c` in the above code) is injecting `AProperty` in an object of type `ChildA` or `ChildB`. I am sure it is of one (because `Parent` is abstract), but NInject sees `DeclaringType` as `Parent`, thus cannot make a decision

Comment: So i think basically what you need is `WhenInjectedInto<ChildA>` but rather than testing whether it's being directly injected into `ChildA` it should also walk up the request tree. Just look at the code of ['WhenInjectedInto'](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/d1660fb7f4816b2fae2c42dd662350d4e223ef60/src/Ninject/Planning/Bindings/BindingConfigurationBuilder.cs).

Comment: Reflection: the declaring type of a member (property) is always the class which specifies it (in this case the parent class). This is not about what ninject "sees" but rather how .net handles / defines types and reflection.
So `Member.DeclaringType` cannot (ever) help in what you're trying to do (no matter which DI container you use). Also see [here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding#specifying-constraints-on-the-type-binding-using-the-built-in-attribute-based-helpers), specifically the section mentioning the difference between "Target, Member, Class".

Comment: Why not have an interface for both, you can still have your abstract class.

Comment: @PPC In that case you need to make `AProperty` *virtual* and override it in both `ChildA` and `ChildB`. If overriden, the *declaring type* will be the class overriding the property and not the base class where it is initially delcared. I was wrong in my first comment about overriding no being helpful, I initially thought *declaring type* would still return the base class but that is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i get you right, you want to inject a different `AnObject` into property `AProperty` depending on which sub-class it's injected into.

---

Hint: If there's no compelling reasons to do otherwise, you should use constructor injection instead of property (or method) injection.

---

So this basically means you want a combination of `WhenInjectedInto<>` and `WhenAnyAncestorMatches`. You can have a look at the implementation of `WhenInjectedInto<>` [here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/d1660fb7f4816b2fae2c42dd662350d4e223ef60/src/Ninject/Planning/Bindings/BindingConfigurationBuilder.cs) and use the same logic as an argument to `WhenAnyAncestorMatches` or you can use a somewhat dirty trick to combine both:

```
var binding = Kernel.Bind<AnObject>().ToConstructor(..);

Func<IRequest, bool> whenInjectedIntoCondition = 
    binding.WhenInjectedInto<int>().BindingConfiguration.Condition;

binding.WhenAnyAncestorMatches(c => whenInjectedIntoCondition(c.Request));
```

---

With constructor injection this works, I'm not a 100% sure if it also works with property injection.